# I want to send a push notification when there is a change in web server's mysql database. Is it possible?

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

I want to create a system like sending push notifications to the registered device id's whenever there is a change in the online web server's MySQL databases.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474012/invoke-pusher-when-mysql-has-changed

Comment: That would require to install the UDF sys_eval and the source code @GramHolo

Comment: There isn't a method out of the box within MySQL.. PostgreSQL has a out of the box solution with LISTEN / NOTIFY  -> ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html)  Stackoverflow example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852595/real-time-postgresql-client-updates-based-on-notification

Comment: Other solution can be a combination between android and node.js.. Node.js support's clients push when you use websockets.. For example one client inserts you detect a successful insert and notify all connected clients with a event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Maxwell Daemon](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) to monitor the mysql binary logs updates and then send the push notification to your devices.